# how to remove array cell in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel

in laravel i have tow array like this

array one

```
array: [
  0 => "title1"
  1 => null
  2 => "title 3"
  3 => null
]
```

and this is my another array

```
array:4 [
  0 => "value 1"
  1 => null
  2 => null
  3 => "value 4"
]
```

i want to combine these tow array , so i used this method

```
array_combine($array1, $array2);
```

and this was the dd() result

```
array:3 [
  "title1" => "value 1"
  "" => "value 4"
  "title 3" => null
]
```

so far there is not any problem
my question is how can i remove mereged array where key or value is null or empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage Laravel Collection

```php
$merged = [
  "title1" => "value 1",
  "" => "value 4",
  "title 3" => null
];

$result = collect($merged)
    ->reject(fn($value, $key) => empty($value) || empty($key))
    ->all();

//$result will be
[
  "title1" => "value 1",
]
```

Comment: tnk u so much , can u explain why we use collect not array?

Comment: We use collection because we use Laravel. Similar output can be achieved via **array_filter** I guess, but with Laravel Collection it is much more expressive

Comment: tnk u agian ,u help me very much